# Why is my app deployed through App Engine not able to connect to Cloud SQL postgres database?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, sequelize.js

I attempted to follow the guide here https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/using-cloud-sql-postgres
to integrate my app with the Cloud SQL postgres instance.  However I keep getting an error:

> Updating service [default] (this may take several minutes)...failed.
>   ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] Application startup
>   error:
>
> testpostgres@1.0.0 start /app node app.js
>
> Unhandled rejection SequelizeConnectionError: connect ENOENT
>   /cloudsql/test-postgress:us-central1:testpostgress/.s.PGSQL.5432 at
>   connection.connect.err
>   (/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/connection-manager.js:128:24) at Connection.connectingErrorHandler
>   (/app/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:123:14) at emitOne
>   (events.js:116:13) at Connection.emit (events.js:211:7) at
>   Socket.reportStreamError
>   (/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:71:10) at emitOne
>   (events.js:116:13) at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7) at emitErrorNT
>   (internal/streams/destroy.js:64:8) at _combinedTickCallback
>   (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11) at process._tickCallback
>   (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)

It must be a problem with my configuration, but I have tried everything I can think of. You can see or clone my project here:
https://github.com/fractalfrenzy/GCS_postgres_test

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing of Node.js, but have a long experience with Java/Python/Go runtime.
Have you opened your CloudSQL instance for connection?
Try this: [Configuring IP Connectivity](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/configure-ip)